# Swagger Spring-MVC/SwaggerUI Authentication

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I've been attempting to set up Swagger Spring-MVC and Swagger UI using the latest version of the SpringMVC implementation here : [Swagger Spring-MVC](https://github.com/martypitt/swagger-springmvc)

I've been able to get the initial setup working, but when I navigate to my SwaggerUI page, I get an error saying that it can't access my api because "server returned undefined". When I look in firebug, it says that it's getting a 401 Unauthorized.

When you first navigate to the SwaggerUI URL, a dialog pops up for me to enter my user-name and password. I know it's correct because I can manually use my resources with the same credentials.

My assumption is that I have Swagger adding some extra form of authorization to the controllers that it generates for itself. I tried setting it to Basic Auth, and just not setting the auth at all, but that doesn't work either.

Does anyone know what my solution would be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I posted this question, I immediately realized the answer.

The default URL provider is set to 127.0.0.1:8080 and I was navigating to localhost:8080. They resolve to the same place, but I guess the authentication from one won't be applied to the other. Silly me.